# Wait for constructor of injected service to finish before executing tests in Karma 4 / Angular 7

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular7

I'm injecting a service like this:

```
it('name of test', inject([ Service], (hcs: Service) => {
    const pipe = new MyPipe(hcs);
    const expectedResult = ...
    //Here the constructor of the hcs-service has to be completet, otherwise the Pipe fails
    const result = pipe.transform(...);
    expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
}));
```

I need to run the constructor of the service before I start executing the transform method of my pipe. During runtime, this is not an issue as this pipe is always a reaction to a user action. But in my tests, it fails because the constructor hasn't run yet.

What would be a good way to solve this?

Edit: As Arif pointed out in a comment. The problem is that my constructor executes async tasks. Thanks :)

Comment: constructor is synchronous. It is not possible for the line next to execute before constructor finishes. Are you sure your constructor doesn't do anything async?

Comment: Yes you are right. The actions of the constructor are async. rsjx subscriptions

Comment: Then you have to use fakeAsync and tick

Comment: @Arif yeah you are right, should have been obvious. If you make this an answer, I mark it a correct.

Comment: I tried to wrap our conversation into an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object's constructor will always be executed first. Unless you have an async code there.

As you mentioned in comments that was the problem in your case.

To wait in your test for async function to complete you have to use [fakeAsync](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync) and [tick](https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef#tick)

```
it('name of test', fakeAsync(inject([ Service], (hcs: Service) => {
    const pipe = new MyPipe(hcs);

    tick();

    const expectedResult = ...
    //Here the constructor of the hcs-service has to be completet, otherwise the Pipe fails
    const result = pipe.transform(...);
    expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
})));
```